# Estimating integral by Monte Carlo method

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo

I'm trying to solve the following problem

> Use Monte-Carlo methods to find a $95 \%$ confidence interval for the following integral: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left( \frac{1}{2}\left[x^2 - \frac{x(y-1)}{10} +(y-1)^2\right] \right ) dx dy$$

Now, my first thoughts were that this function looks similar to a [bivariate normal density](https://math.tntech.edu/ISR/Introduction_to_Probability/Joint_Distributions/thispage/newnode6.html).
For example, considering a bivariate normal distribution with parameters $\mu_1 = 0, \mu_2 = \sigma_1 = \sigma_2 = 1$ and $\rho = \frac{1}{20}$ we would have the density

$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{399/400}} \ \exp\left(-\frac{400}{399} \ g(x,y) \right)$$
where $g(x)$ is the function being integrated, that is,

$$ g(x)= \exp\left( \frac{1}{2}\left[x^2 - \frac{x(y-1)}{10} +(y-1)^2\right] \right ). $$

I have tried to express the integral as some kind of expected value under the bivariate normal distribution, so as to simulate values under that distribution, but somehow I always end up getting stuck. If anyone has any idea on how to proceed, I would appreciate it very much.

Thanks!

Comment: The normal distribution has the shape $\exp(\mathbf{-} x^2)$, not $\exp(x^2)$.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I said similar. I was still hoping there might be a way to write the expression as an expectation of the bivariate normal density.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is a typo in the text of the exercise (and this is quite likely!), Monte Carlo methods are superfluous for computing this integral since the integrand diverges at $\pm\infty$. Hence
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left( \frac{1}{2}\left[x^2 - \frac{x(y-1)}{10} +(y-1)^2\right] \right )\, \text{d}x\,\text{d}y=+\infty$$

Comment: Thank you, I also think it is a typo!